# Ubuntu 22.04 crashing on upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, installation, updates

Fresh install as Guest VM (virtualbox) Ubuntu can't upgrade

```
Err:4 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 amd64 2.36.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
```

So far tried deleting sources file + update + upgrade

what you said worked, but as soon as I update again its the same problem
Err:10 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/main amd64 Packages
404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]

I removed sources.list and sources.list.d and it seems to be working better(update upgrade), but i still get this end of update,
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/jammy/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/jammy-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/jammy-backports/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/jammy-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

```
update
sudo apt install build-essential
E: Unable to locate package build-essential
```

Comment: I have Ubuntu 22.04 running as a VM in VMware. Try running Ubuntu Software Updater.  Make sure Live Patch is running This works here.

Comment: Also, if you can get to a terminal session, run this:   ......    sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove

Comment: I can certainly reach the IP `185.125.190.39` and my browser shows the index of the repository. Are you sure that you have a working internet connection?

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Did this resolve your issue?

Comment: Could you [edit] your answer and explain why this will help the OP?

Comment: This does not help.